# How do i catch an error in a int parsed from string?

Tags: c#

I am having trubble finding a way that works and helps to catch an error input. I need to handle if the input is not a 1 or a 2. Like . or a - or just any letter. I have tried catch and well nothing seems to work :/

Someone that have an idea for me to try? I am greatfull for any suggestions!! Thx in advance!

Regards

The code i have written so far looks like this:

```
console.WriteLine();
Console.Write("Make your choice: ");


int myinput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (myinput == 1)
{
FirstEvent();
}
if (myinput == 2)
{
SecondEvent();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually we use the TryParse methods

```
int myinput = 0;
if(false == int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out myInput))
   // Error, not an integer
   Console.WriteLine("Please input 1 or 2");
else
{
    if (myinput == 1) 
    { 
        FirstEvent(); 
    } 
    else if (myinput == 2) 
    { 
        SecondEvent(); 
    } 
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Please input 1 or 2");
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason I don't know to write if(false == int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out myInput)) instead of just if(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out myInput))?

Comment: @FrancescoBaruchelli, no there is no specific reason. I prefer that way because (at my age) sometimes the NOT character escapes my eyesight.

Comment: I bow my head at your kung-fu! Thanks a million Steve!! It works like a charm! Have a wonderful day! Regards